# how to request additional scopes from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I redirect users to the URL

```
display = '&display=page',
state = '&state=facebook_auth_' + csrfToken,
scope = '&scope=' + this.scopes,
redirect = '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUrl,
facebookURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + this.clientId + redirect + scope + display + state;
```

For some reason, when I try to request new permissions by redirecting users to the URL above, Facebook does not show a prompt asking the user for access to the new permissions. What am I doing wrong

Comment: What URL do you redirect them to?

Comment: are you trying with an app admin or with a random user? do you know about login review?